Simplify making a generic typed value from a reflect value
I have Go code that receives a reflection value and needs to work with it as a generic. To convert the parameter, I've gotten the following to work. Is there a simpler way to achieve the goal?
func toValue[T any](v reflect.Value) T {
    v = v.Convert(reflect.TypeFor[T]())
    var src any
    reflect.ValueOf(&src).Elem().Set(v)

    var dest T
    reflect.ValueOf(&dest).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(src))
    return dest
}

I'm using this in a general-purpose parser that lets the client use generics to produce typed output.

It would be clearer if there was more than this example to show the higher-level problem. I've mixed reflection with generics when the internal stuff needs reflection, but I want a more convenient outer signature/interface for users. But it's gotta be a clear benefit.

My case is a parser, which has a proprietary format, but I decided to make the parsing interface like json marshalling. The client supplies its data structure much like json marshaller. Generics helps with the case where an ordered map is required. I have an ordered map implementation that is effectively map[k]v but with order in its structs, and k and v are generic types.

Simplify the function by using a type assertion on the result of the conversion:
func toValue[T any](v reflect.Value) T {
    return v.Convert(reflect.TypeFor[T]()).Interface().(T)
}

(As with the code in the question, this function panics when v cannot be converted to a T).
https://go.dev/play/p/mg5NjuUh_Tu

It's unclear why you specifically need to use a type conversion in this reflection code. If you only need to extract a concrete type from reflect.Value, you can type assert right away:
func toValue[T any](v reflect.Value) T {
    return v.Interface().(T)
}

At call site this looks like:
u := // some reflect.Value
v := toValue[uint64](u)

But here the named function is just boilerplate. You could type-assert in line:
u := // some reflect.Value
v := u.Interface().(uint64)

The point here is that sooner or later up the call stack the type argument you'd use to instantiate toValue[T](u) is known. So instead of doing conversions, you could just assert the reflect.Value's interface. This also allows you to handle unexpected situations with the comma-ok idiom instead of panicking:
v, ok := u.Interface().(uint64)

of if you want to hide it in a function:
func toValue[T any](v reflect.Value) (T, error) {
    u, ok := v.Interface().(T)
    if !ok {
        var t T // just a zero value
        return t, fmt.Errorf("v has not type %T", t)
    }
    return u, nil
}


Because in the parser, the reflection value has the same kind but not necessarily the same type. Think of the json parser - the text values read from the stream are all string. But the output generic type like type MyType string needs conversion. So the answer from @Isra Hirsi was the way I went.
